# Crontab doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I get an issue using Crontab. My script is working standalone but it is not working using Crontab.

Environment : Ubuntu

Crontab (sudo crontab -e) : `0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/GestiawebParser/index.js`

**Edit #1 :**

`which node` : `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: What is the output of `which node`?

Comment: Add MAILTO in your cron and you should receive an email with any errors.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson program node is find since given in absolute path, however it might be a shell script (or a binary) that relay on command not in cron's $PATH value.

Comment: See edit #1 for the command `which node`. Ok so I need to execute `node /var/www/GestiawebParser/index.js` using a shell script ?

Comment: Is it really on 2 separate lines?

Comment: @tonymx227 As Archemar said, `node` may be a script that relies on `$PATH` to be set in a particular way.

Comment: Yes, but when I execute the command `node ./index.js` in the right folder it works. I don't think that the problem is about cron's $PATH value.

Comment: What does the does the Javascript do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crontab issues can be solved by:

- test the script outside of crontab (you did this)
- add a test script to ensure it's enabled (like `* * * * * /bin/echo test > /test.txt`)
- use [env](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env) to test and correct environment settings (a common alternative to exporting the PATH variable is to use absolute paths but obviously that only works for executables and PATH) ([which](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which), [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file))
- prefix your crontab with MAILTO or otherwise collect logging information (like suffixing with `>> /out.txt 2>> /err.txt; /bin/echo $? >> /return.txt`)